# Eclipse Java code formatter

Tags: eclipse, coding-style, formatting, code-formatting, eclipse-formatter

I would like the Eclipse formatter to format Java method declarations in a specific way, is this possible? If not, is there a way to define my own custom formatting?

The code should look like this for a short method (ie. shorter than the linewidth):

```java
  private ClassNumberTwo methodNumberTwo(ClassNumberTwo parameterOne) throws ExceptionNumberOne
  {
    return parameterOne;
  }
```

And like this for a long method (ie. longer than the linewidth):

```java
  private ClassNumberOne methodNumberOne(
    ClassNumberTwo parameterOne,
    ClassNumberOne parameterTwo,
    ClassNumberThree parameterThree,
    ClassNumberFour parameterFour,
    ClassNumberFive parameterFive)
      throws ExceptionNumberOne,
      ExceptionNumberTwo,
      ExceptionNumberThree
  {
    return parameterTwo;
  }
```

I know where to find code formatter settings in Eclipse, but I can't find any setting that will format the code exactly like the example.

Comment: why do you want this strange behavior (300 vs 120)?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I will edit and try to make a clearer example.

Answer (score 3):

1. Window
2. Preferences
3. Java
4. Code Style
5. Formatter
6. Click the edit button.
7. Line Wrapping
8. Constructor Declarations
9. Parameters
10. Set Line Wrapping Policy: Wrap All Elements, Every Element on a New Line

There are various options within the formatter, you may need to adjust different settings to get exactly what you want.

[image]

Comment: I have tried all the settings I could find, but couldn't make them do what I want.